# Why is this code throwing error after compiling

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, pysimplegui, pygithub

I made a script and it works perfectly but when I compile it with pyinstaller

`pyinstaller --onefile --icon='icon.ico' dmi.py`

It throws error, but if I don't compile it works

I know Github module is throwing error. This is the code which throwing error:

```py
import PySimpleGUIQt as Sg
from github import Github
from urllib import parse

g = Github("ghp_**********************************")
img_data = (g.get_user().get_repo('python-files')).get_contents(
    parse.quote('create.ico'), ref="main").content.replace('\n', '').encode()

layout = [
    [Sg.Text('                                                     ')]
]
window = Sg.Window("Add Tags", layout, icon=img_data, resizable=False, finalize=True)
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == Sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        window.close()
        break
```

The code below works even after compiling:

```py
import base64
import PySimpleGUIQt as Sg
import requests
header = {"Authorization": "token ghp_*******************************",
          "Accept": "application/vnd.github.v4.raw"}
encoded = base64.b64encode((requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WoLvES-2x0/python-files/main/create.ico', headers=header)).content)
layout = [
    [Sg.Text('                                                     ')]
]
window = Sg.Window("Add Tags", layout, icon=encoded, resizable=False, finalize=True)
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == Sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        window.close()
        break
```

although I can do this in other way but main issue I'll face without this is

`Get file name of all files in a repo`

```py
g_f_name = [str(i).replace('ContentFile(path="', '').replace('")', '') for i in (g.get_user().get_repo('node-files')).get_contents('') if i]
```

And
`commit changes to repo`

```py
repo.update_file(repo.get_contents('tags.txt').path, "committing files", tags_string, repo.get_contents('tags.txt').sha, branch="main")
```

error Is

```py
C:\pythoncharm\pythonProject4\dist>dmi.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dmi.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\WoLvES\AppData\Local\Temp\embedded.rtin1sym.zip\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "github\__init__.py", line 56, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\WoLvES\AppData\Local\Temp\embedded.rtin1sym.zip\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "github\MainClass.py", line 59, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\WoLvES\AppData\Local\Temp\embedded.rtin1sym.zip\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "github\Event.py", line 32, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\WoLvES\AppData\Local\Temp\embedded.rtin1sym.zip\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "github\NamedUser.py", line 44, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\WoLvES\AppData\Local\Temp\embedded.rtin1sym.zip\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "github\Organization.py", line 50, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\WoLvES\AppData\Local\Temp\embedded.rtin1sym.zip\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "github\Repository.py", line 125, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\WoLvES\AppData\Local\Temp\embedded.rtin1sym.zip\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "github\PublicKey.py", line 34, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\WoLvES\AppData\Local\Temp\embedded.rtin1sym.zip\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "nacl\public.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\WoLvES\AppData\Local\Temp\embedded.rtin1sym.zip\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "nacl\bindings\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\WoLvES\AppData\Local\Temp\embedded.rtin1sym.zip\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "nacl\bindings\crypto_aead.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\WoLvES\AppData\Local\Temp\embedded.rtin1sym.zip\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
  File "C:\Users\WoLvES\AppData\Local\Temp\embedded.rtin1sym.zip\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_cffi_backend'
[33116] Failed to execute script 'dmi' due to unhandled exception!
```

Comment: Could you add the error to your question with an [edit]?

Comment: I can't cause I don't have privilage to add images, as the error shows in console and the error closes before I pause the console, it stays for 100 or 200 ms,
I got to see the error by using 'Instant replay' but it's not in text format

Comment: So, this error you're talking about is probably quite important for us to be able to answer the question. Tell us as much as you can. See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: If you run the program from a console the console will remain afterwards.

Comment: When that happens for me I like to take a video of the screen with my phone and just slide through it really slowly to read it (not fancy but effective).

Comment: @Elan-R Instant replay is better way clear

Comment: Btw Added error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

importing

```py
import _cffi_backend
```

solves the issue, what I think is Pyinstaller somehow misses this module while compiling, and PyGithub need this module, Although in editor this grayed out but it works